# calculate the maximum value in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory like this :

```
myapp.factory('JobOffersByCounteryFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {
        getList: function() {
            return $http.get('data/offres_par_pays.JSON')
                .then(function(response) {
//....code

                }, function(error) {
                    return 'There was an error getting data';
                });
        },
        getHighestNumberOfOffers: function() {
            var n = 0;
            $http.get('data/offres_par_pays.JSON')
                .then(function(response) {
                    n = Math.max.apply(Math, response.data['nb']);
                }, function(error) {
                    return 'There was an error getting data';
                });
            return n;
        }
    };
    return factory;
});
```

This factory will return an object with two functions in it, the second function will return the maximum number in an array which is in this case `response.data['nb']`

In my controller I tested that function :

```
console.log(JobOffersByCounteryFactory.getHighestNumberOfOffers());
```

but I'm always getting the value `0`.

I tried to affect some number to the `n` variable like this : `n = 12;` but I'm always getting the value `0` it seems that the value of the `n` variable didn't change inside `$http.get('data/offres_par_pays.JSON').then(function(response)`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Short answer is that you can't return `n` based on `response`. Though, Angular already has one of the common suggestions – `$q` promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect `asynchronous` call to work synchronously. Because you could never know that when it will get completed.

For getting control over it you something which will tell that `async` call has been completed or failed, so that is what promise is. Basically `$http.get` has returns `promise` object. 
You should return a promise from the method `getHighestNumberOfOffers`, Place `.then` function over it which will have success and error callback in it.
 & on promise success you need to return the newly calculated variable value.

**Code**

```
getHighestNumberOfOffers: function() {
  var n = 0;
  return $http.get('data/offres_par_pays.JSON')
    .then(function(response) {
    n = Math.max.apply(Math, response.data['nb']);
    return n;
  }, function(error) {
    return 'There was an error getting data';
  });
}
```

While doing `console.log(JobOffersByCounteryFactory.getHighestNumberOfOffers())` you will only get the promise object which is being returned by the `getHighestNumberOfOffers`(as per above suggestion). For getting exact value you should put that `console.log` inside the `.then` function of `getHighestNumberOfOffers` service method.

```
JobOffersByCounteryFactory.getHighestNumberOfOffers().then(function(n){
   console.log(n)
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks :)